ASP.NET Core 6 ApiGateway 404 not found
I installed Apigateway. And apart from that, I have a few APIs. All APIs work in Postman with their own URL addresses. But when I try to go with the baseurl address in ocelot, I get a 404 not found error. Where is the problem with you?
This is my first time asking a question here. I'm sorry if I gave the code on the screen incorrectly.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

// JWT kimlik doğrulama ayarları
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:ValidIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:ValidAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Secret"]))
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication(); // JWT kimlik doğrulama
app.UseAuthorization();
await app.UseOcelot();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Setting/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Setting/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5101"
  }
}


Postman has a control panel that shows the entire http request including all the http headers.  Postman automatically adds headers to the request while c# does not.  So  you have to take the missing header that are found in Postman and add to the c# code.

Could you please also include the snippet how you are sending the reuqest to the ocelot endpoint along with the baseurl address?

Hi @Betul, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.


I installed Apigateway. And apart from that, I have a few APIs. All
APIs work in Postman with their own URL addresses. But when I try to
go with the baseurl address in ocelot, I get a 404 not found error.
Where is the problem with you?

Based on your shared code snippet and description, I have treid to investigate your issue and I found couple of inconsistencies.
First of all, call await app.UseOcelot();  after app.UseEndpoints(). This ensures that the Ocelot middleware is properly integrated into the request pipeline.
Secondly, I haven;'t seen routing middleware reference within your program.cs file. So Add app.UseRouting() before app.UseEndpoints() to ensure proper routing configuration.
Apart from that, verify that the paths specified in DownstreamPathTemplate and UpstreamPathTemplate match the actual paths of your downstream services and the desired upstream paths.
Considering above point, you could refactor your program.cs as following:
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
await app.UseOcelot(); 
app.Run();

Note: Please refer this document if you need additional assistance.
